# loan calculator that implements multiple methods

Tags: java, methods

I have been working on a program that is a Java loan payment calculator for my comp sci class.  The programs requriements are:

1. ask user for loan amount, annual interest rate, and number of months
2. call a method to calculate and return the monthly interest rate
3. call a method to calculate and return the monthly payments
4. call a method to print a loan statement showing the amount borrowed, annual interest rate, the number of months and the monthly payment.

This is my first time working with multiple methods.  I have developed the code so far as shown below.  The netbeans editor is not giving me any errors, however, it does not print the statements from my last method.  My questions are:

1. are my methods set up correctly and passing parameters correctly
2. why won't the statements print at the end
3. am i capturing my other methods correctly? Do i need to enter variables in the main method and then call them in the final method.
4. is any of my code redundant?

I am not really sure how to proceed from here.

```
public class CarLoan {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare variables for main method
    double loanAmount;//double value loan amount 
    double annualInterestRate;//double value interest rate
    int numberOfMonths;//int value for number of months
    double monthlyPayment;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your loan.");
    loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate as a decimal. Ex. 7.5% = .075");
    annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of months you have to pay back your loan.");
    numberOfMonths = keyboard.nextInt();

}
*************************************************

public static double calcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate){
    double monthlyInterestRate;
        monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12);
        return monthlyInterestRate;
}//end method CalcMonthlyInterestRate
**************************************************************************************

    public static double calcMonthlyPayment(double monthlyInterestRate, double loanAmount, int            numberOfMonths     ){
    double monthlyPayment;
    double calcMonthlyPayment;
        calcMonthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate*loanAmount)/(1-(1+monthlyInterestRate)-numberOfMonths);
        return monthlyPayment = calcMonthlyPayment;
}//end method CalcMonthlyPayment
****************************************************************************************
       public static void loanStatment (double loanAmount, double annualInterestRate, intnumberOfMonths,  double monthlyPayment){
 System.out.println("Your loan amount is " +loanAmount);
 System.out.println(annualInterestRate);
 System.out.println(numberOfMonths);
 System.out.println(monthlyPayment);
  }


 }//end main method


}//end main method
```

Comment: why are u posting the same question again and again. You should better spend time on reading java language basics.

Comment: The logic of your app is actually the main() method.  However, you have never invoked any other methods you developed in the main(), then how do you expect it to work?  And, please proper indent your code.  It is just ***HORRIBLE***

Comment: I was unsure if my edits would be seen elsewhere.  Additionally, I am not getting errors in my editor and am really unsure why this is not working.  According to my text this should work.  It is a first edition written by my professor which is very abstract and does not provide examples.  I am kind of under the gun at this point and did not expect this assignment to take this long.  Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your main method like shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarLoan {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare variables for main method
    double loanAmount;//double value loan amount 
    double annualInterestRate;//double value interest rate
    int numberOfMonths;//int value for number of months
    double monthlyPayment;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your loan.");
    loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate as a decimal. Ex. 7.5% = .075");
    annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of months you have to pay back your loan.");
    numberOfMonths = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your monthly payment.");
    monthlyPayment = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Your monthly interest rate is ");
    System.out.println(calcMonthlyInterestRate(annualInterestRate));

    System.out.println("Your monthly payment is ");
    System.out.println(calcMonthlyPayment(calcMonthlyInterestRate(annualInterestRate),loanAmount,numberOfMonths));

    loanStatment(loanAmount,annualInterestRate,numberOfMonths,monthlyPayment);


}


public static double calcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate){
    double monthlyInterestRate;
        monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12);
        return monthlyInterestRate;
}//end method CalcMonthlyInterestRate


    public static double calcMonthlyPayment(double monthlyInterestRate, double loanAmount, int            numberOfMonths     ){
    double monthlyPayment;
    double calcMonthlyPayment;
        calcMonthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate*loanAmount)/(1-(1+monthlyInterestRate)-numberOfMonths);
        return monthlyPayment = calcMonthlyPayment;
}//end method CalcMonthlyPayment

 public static void loanStatment (double loanAmount, 
                                                 double annualInterestRate,
                                                 int numberOfMonths, 
                                                 double monthlyPayment){
             System.out.println("Your loan amount is " +loanAmount);
             System.out.println(annualInterestRate);
             System.out.println(numberOfMonths);
             System.out.println(monthlyPayment);
  }


 }//end of CarLoan
```

I would really suggest you read up a little on how main method works in Java.That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your main method and you will see that all you are doing is declaring your variables and receiving input. Your other methods that perform the calculations and the loanStatment (sic) method that prints your results are never called.

I would recommend you read up on the basics as you will waste less of your time with very simple errors like this one.